# Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy SSL Issue

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am attempting to create the following setup using Apache:

```
UserBrowser ----Client Certificate---> LoadBalancer (Apache 2.4)
then
LoadBalancer (Apache 2.4) ----LB Client Certificate ----> Apache 2.2 Web Server
```

So the user connects to the load balancer and provides a client certificate - This works correctly.

A Reverse Proxy then makes the Load Balancer connect to the web server, the webserver requests a certificate from the Load Balancer and I get the following error:

```
Proxy client certificate callback: (0.0.0.0:443) entered
Proxy client certificate callback: (0.0.0.0:443) downstream server wanted client certificate but none are configured
[remote 0.0.0.1:443] SSL Proxy connect failed
[ssl:info] SSL Library Error: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (SSL alert number 40)
[ssl:info] [remote 0.0.0.1:443] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server 0.0.0.0:443)
[ssl:info] [remote 0.0.0.1:443] SSL handshake failed: sending 502
```

Load Balancer Config:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on
Proxytimeout 600

SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "/path/to/keyandcert.pem"
```

Web Server Config:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

This scenario works if I remove SSLVerifyClient from the Web Server, traffic is then loadbalanced. I need to have client verification between the User - LB and between the LB - WS.

Keys + Certs have been generated using 1024 bit long modulus

Can anyone offer an insight into what might be going wrong here?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is off-topic.

Comment: This community is filled with server configuration questions relating to apache, why do you think I posted the question here in the first place :)

Comment: yes, for apache config for programming issues. there's absolutely nothing programming-related in your question, therefore it's purely server configuration only.

Comment: The load balancer creates a _separate_ SSL session between it and the backend server.  And the load balancer cannot use the client's certificate, since the load balancer does not have that certificate's private key.  So if your backend server is expecting the client's certificate, that might be a cause of failure.  If your backend server expects a _different_ certificate, specific to the load balancer, then that arrangement should work.

Comment: Hey Castaglia, yes that's why I mentioned the 2 parts of communication. The Browser to LB has its own certificate; the LB then connects to the WS with its own certificate specified by the "SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile" option, all the certificates are self-signed using the same CA and so should all be accepted.

Comment: I would wireshark the back-end connection and see if the client cert is even being sent.  If it is and the server is disconnecting, then it's probably a validation / trust issue.  Alert 40 is a handshake failure.  I would expect a different error if it was a cert validation issue.

Comment: Wireshark revelas that the Web Server receives the cert. It then responds with an Alert with Handshake Failure. I have tried recreating the certs, all have been created using the same CA, so trust / validation should not be an issue.